# How do I simulate locations when developing a UWP application?

Tags: uwp, geolocation

I'm working on a UWP application that uses Location services. I have some behaviors that occur when the location changes, that I need to test.

The simulator included in Visual Studio does not include any way to simulate a location. I've read that it did have this years ago, but it was removed for some reason.

I thought I could simulate locations myself by hard-coding some location coordinates into my application and processing them, but I'm finding that I can't really do this because all of the objects related to Location are either sealed classes that I can't extend, or internal interfaces that I cannot implement.

I have a lot of code written that uses GeoPosition or GeoCoordinate. It would take me all day if I were to try to refactor my code to eliminate these references. I should be able to define my own mock Position or Coordinate, but I cannot.

Why did Microsoft do this? It seems like they're intentionally trying to prevent us from testing location services. I don't understand it.

I do a lot of work with mobile apps (iOS and Android) and have never encountered any of these problems in those environments.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I simulate locations when developing a UWP application?

For simulating locations when developing a UWP application, you could use Microsoft Emulator. For more please refer  document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator#location-and-driving)

And please note Microsoft emulator [available maximum](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) version is  15063, so you need edit your apps target version before debugging.